# Unable to upgrade recent 1Password through App Store in macOS Big Sur 11.2.3 (20D91)

Tags: macos, applications

For the very first time I cannot upgrade the app through App Store. It fully downloads the upgrade, but when it comes to installation it fails because it cannot quit itself I assume.

[image]

I can force quit all 1Password-related processes except of the Extension Helper. When I try to do this via `ps aux` and `kill -s TERM PID`, **it immediately spawns itself with another PID**.

Any help? I'm on Big Sur 11.2.3 (20D91).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The official support gave me the answer.

1. Quit all browsers
2. Open main 1Password window
3. Press `⌃ + ⌥ + ⌘ + Q` to quit and indeed it quits all processes.

Weird that the CLI approach didn't work.

Anyway - solved.